Android Emulator issues in new Koala Feature Drop 2024.1.2 versions - The emulator process has terminated
After updating to Android Studio Koala Feature Drop 2024.1.2, when I try to run an emulator, it gets killed with this error:  Nexus S API 22 : The emulator process for AVD Nexus_S_API_22 has terminated. It was working correctly in the previous version, but now after installing the new one, it has stopped working. I have created new AVD but nothing found for help.
I have also doing following method to correct this issue but fail.
Methods I have used:
1- I have created many avds but all of them show the same error.
2-I prepared each AVD and then checked. But when the error showed then I also did wipe data and cold boot but it didn't help.
3-I also tried to run it using the given command " C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>.\emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_22 -gpu swiftshader_indirect "  but I get the following error.
ٓqemu-system-i386.exe The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005)
4-I rebooted the computer and checked virtualization in bios setup and it was already enabled.
5-I checked the path in the sdk manager and it was correct. Then uninstalled and reinstalled by unchecking the Android SDK Platform Tools from SDK Tools but still showed the same error.
6- i have settin following Enviromental Variables also.
ANDROID_AVD_HOME
C:\Users\Mustafa.android\avd
ANDROID_SDK_HOME
C:\Users\Mustafa.android
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
I know this issue is very old and there is a lot of information available on it. But the surprise is that I have used almost all the information and methods but still I am unable to solve this problem. Please help to solve this and find a correct way so that other programmers can benefit from it.



Mustafa can you share complete emulator crash log.

The error code 0xc0000005 indicates an Access Violation, which typically means that there’s a problem with permissions or that the application tried to access memory it shouldn't have.

Yes, you are right. But I am already running it as administrator permissions۔

Yes. System has GPU.

I tried all the methods that were available on the internet or that I was aware of. But I was not successful in any way. Finally, I completely wiped Android from my computer and reinstalled it again, and this time there were no issues.

This version of android studio is suck. Everytime I try to create a jetpack compose project and on the build.gradle(app/project) when I add addons it freeze.To work again I have to restart everyytime.
